# How to force programmatically create Thumbnail in Sharepoint 2010 FOUNDATION

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file-icons

I know in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation there is no Thumbnail feature but let me explain my problem 'cause I need just the thumbnail creation invoked programmatically, not to show the image or something like that so if the functionality is exposed by Object Model I can solve my problem.

I have a Web Service that expose some methods. One of the method I must implement had to get the "ID" of the file and return the thumbnail of the selected file.

To me the best could be:

- On file Adding: SPListItem.CREATETHUMBNAIL
- On my Web Service Invocation: return SPListItem.THUMBNAIL

Is there, in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation the possibility to return the Thumbnail of a file? There are other ways to implement it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a thumbnail image from SharePoint 2010 OOTB just using some URL manipulation on the image URL in the library. For example if you have an image at the URL:

```
http://server/site/library/image.jpg
```

You can get a thumbnail for this with the URL:

```
http://server/site/library/_t/image_jpg.jpg
```

To generate a thumbnail you must insert **_t** as an additional directory in the URL and append **_[extension]** to the filename before the extension.

Comment: You also the `_w` prefix for "web" scaled images (640px if I'm right)

Comment: That's right Steve, if the image is larger than 640px wide, otherwise _W will just return the image. The thumbnails generated with _t are 160px wide.

Comment: Works also for PPT, PDF and so on or only for images? Thank you!

Comment: One would assume this only works for images. If you are looking for an icon for PDF, PPT etc then use an image. If you are looking for a thumbnail preview of the contents of a PDF, PPT etc whilst definitely acheivable programmatically it would be a considerable undertaking.